# An unfriendly question about "friendly" binary sequences

Tags: combinatorics, permutations, contest-math

**Question(IOQM-2022)**: A binary sequence is a sequence in which each term is equal to $0$ or $1$. A binary sequence is called friendly if each term is adjacent to at least one term that is equal to 1. For example, the sequence $0,1,1,0,0,1,1,1$ is friendly. Let $F_n$ denote the number of friendly binary sequences with $n$ terms. Find the smallest positive integer $n\geq 2$ such that $F_n>100$.

What I have tried till now:
1.We note that the second and the penultimate term of a friendly sequence must be $1$ as the end terms must be adjacent to $1$ for the sequence to be friendly. We can't construct new seqences out of those $n-length$ sequences that end with $0$, since we already figured out that the number at penultimate place has to be 1.
2. Suppose we have an $n$-length friendly sequence that ends with $1$. We can construct two new friendly sequence of length $n+1$ by appending a $1$ and $0$.
Using these tw0 observations, I tried to calculate $F_n$ for small values of $n$.
$F_2=1$
$F_3=3$
$(1,1,0),(0,1,1),(1,1,1)$ are the terms here. We note that we have got an extra term other than thoe that 1. and 2. made us construct. This is (0,1,1).
Note the tranformation:
$(1,1,1)\rightarrow (0,1,1)$.
3. Thus, we can take the $(n+1)$ sequences created in step 2. that end in $1$ and take the $n-1$ th term(which is $1$ here) from step 1 and replace it by zero.

Thus, if $x$ is the number of $n$-friendly sequences ending with $1$, then
$F_{n+1}=2.x+x=3x$. Further, the number of $n+1$-length friendly sequences ending with zero
will always be half the number of those ending with one.
Further, if $x=\frac{2F_n}{3}$, then, we get,
$F_{n+1}= 2F_n$
And $x=2\frac{F_n}{3}$ for $n=3$ and thus, we can proceed by induction to obtain:
$F_{n+1}=F_n.2$ for $n\geq 3$

I am skeptical about my deductions. Can anybody help me solve this problem?

Comment: So you are suggesting $F_4=2F_3=6$. But I only see $1111$, $1110$, $0111$, and $0110$, so $F_4=4$.

Comment: But please edit your post to include the source of this problem, it has appeared again on this site.

Comment: Aren't 01 and 10 also friendly?  And 010?

Comment: @GerryMyerson what about $1001$ ,$1010$,$0101$ ?

Comment: We can't consider 1010 as 1 is surrounded by two zeroes and thus, can't be friendly.

Comment: @SalmonFish $1001$? That's not friendly. The first term is only adjacent to a $0$, so it's not adjacent to a $1$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First let's consider the related question: how many subsets $A \subseteq \{1,\dots,n\}$ are there such $A$ does not contain two consecutive elements? Denote this number by $g(n)$. If $A$ contains 1, then $A$ cannot contain $2$ and $A \setminus \{1\}$ is a subset of $\{3,\dots,n\}$ not containing any consecutive elements. This gives us $g(n-2)$ possibilities. If $A$ does not contain 1, then $A$ is a subset of $\{2,\dots,n\}$ not containing any consecutive elements, so there $g(n-1)$ possibilities. Hence, $g(n) = g(n-2) + g(n-1)$.
Note that $g(1) = 2$ and $g(2) = 3$. This implies that $g(n)$ is the $(n+2)$th Fibonnaci number (with the convention that the first two Fibonacci numbers are 1).
Let's denote the $n$th Fibonacci number by $\mathcal F_n$.

Now, let's look at the friendly sequences of length $n$. A sequence $S$ is friendy iff the set $A$ of positions where $S$ equals $0$ does not contain $2$ or $n-1$, and $A$ does not contain two numbers at distance $2$ from each other. So we can look at the odd and even positions separately. Define the following sets.

- $A_1 = \{ k : S \text{ has a 0 in position } 2k-1 \}$,
- $A_2 = \{ k : S \text{ has a 0 in position } 2k \}$.

If $n$ is even, then $A_1$ and $A_2$ must be subsets without consecutive elements of $\{ 1,\dots,\frac n 2 -1\}$ and $\{2,\dots,\frac n 2\}$ respectively. Note that we chose the bounds of these intervals to exclude that $S$ has a $0$ in position $n-1$ or 2.
Therefore $F_n = g(\frac n2 - 1)^2 = \mathcal F_{\frac n2 + 1}^2$.

If $n$ is odd, then $A_1$ and $A_2$ must be subsets without consecutive elements of $\{1,\dots,\frac{n+1}2\}$ and $\{2,\dots,\frac{n-3}2\}$ respectively.
Therefore $F_n = g(\frac{n+1}2) \cdot g(\frac{n-5}2) = \mathcal F_{\frac{n+5}2} \cdot \mathcal F_{\frac{n-1}2}$.

When is $F_n > 100$? If $n$ is even, we need $\mathcal F_{\frac n2 + 1} > 10$, or $\frac n2 + 1 \geq 7$, which gives us 12.
If $n$ is odd, we need $\mathcal F_{\frac{n+5}2} \cdot \mathcal F_{\frac{n-1}2} \geq 100$, which happes for $\mathcal F_8 \times \mathcal F_5 = 21 \cdot 5$. So we get $\frac{n+5}2 \geq 8$ or $n \geq 11$.
Thus, $F_n > 100$ if and only if $n \geq 11$.

Comment: I calculated $149$ friendly binary sequence for $n=8$ using analytic combinatoric techniques

Comment: @SalmonFish: the number of binary sequences of length 8, which have a 1 in positions 2 and 7 equals the number of binary sequences of length 6, i.e. $2^6 = 64$. So it is definitely not possible that there are 149 friendly binary sequences of length 8.

Comment: we do not have to have ones in position $2$ and $7$ , assume that we have ones in position $1$ and $8$ , then you can put ones and zeros in position $2$ and $7$

Comment: the question says that each character must be adjacent to atleast one $1$ , so we should eliminate the sequences that contain $000$

Comment: @SalmonFish You need to fuss a little at the beginning and end, since 0100 is not friendly but doesn't contain 000.

Comment: @SalmonFish I guess we are working with different definitions of adjacency. I do not consider an element to be adjacent to itself. Then you do need a 1 at position 2, since position 1 is only adjacent to position 2. Likewise for position $n-1$.

Comment: You confused me for a minute by using a capital eff for two different things, until I realized they were two different effs. Anyway, the formulas in terms of the Fibonacci's are nice (and are noted at https://oeis.org/A195971).

Answer (score 4):

I initially misunderstood the problem.  I agree with SamA3aensen's count, which begins 1, 3, 4, 5, 9, 16.  Here are the sets of friendly binary sequences up to length 6.
\begin{gather}
\{11\}, \\
\{111, 110, 011\}, \\
\{1111, 1110, 0111, 0110\},\\
\{11111, 11110, 11011, 01111, 01110\} \\
\{111111, 111110, 111011, 110111, 110110, 110011, 011111, 011110, 011011\}
\end{gather}
Here are the 16 length 7 friendly sequences ordered by number of zeros.
\begin{align}
\{1111111, \\
1111110, 1111011, 1110111, 1101111, 0111111, \\
1110110, 1110011, 1101110, 1100111, 0111110, 0111011, 0110111, \\
1100110, 0110110, 0110011\}
\end{align}

This is OEIS sequence [A195971](https://oeis.org/A195971) which includes this interpretation.  The recurrence is $a(n) = a(n-1) + a(n-3) + a(n-4)$.

Here's a combinatorial understanding of the recurrence.

- For the length $n-1$ friendly sequences, add a 1 before the last bit.
- For the length $n-3$ friendly sequences that end in a 1, add 101 before the last bit.  For those that end in a 0, add 101 before the 10 at the end.
- For the length $n-4$ friendly sequences that end in a 1, add 1001 before the last bit.  For those that end in a 0, and 1001 before the 10 at the end.

Old answer below (counting sequences with each 0 adjacent to at least one 1).

---

As I understand the definition, this is a Tribonacci sequence, [A000213](https://oeis.org/A000213) in the OEIS, recurrence $a(n) = a(n-1) + a(n-2) + a(n-3)$ with initial values 3, 5, 9 (without worrying about vacuous shorter binary sequences), corresponding to $\{01, 10, 11\}$, $\{010, 011, 101, 110, 111\}$, and $\{0101, 0110, 0111, 1001, 1010, 1011, 1101, 1110, 1111\}$.

This would confirm Salmon Fish's answer of $n = 8$ as the smallest length with over 100 terms, although it would be 105 rather than 149.  The sequence starts $3, 5, 9, 17, 31, 57, 105, 193, 355$.

For the recurrence, put a 1 at the end of the length $n-1$ sequences and a $10$ at the end of the length $n-2$ sequences.  The procedure for length $n-3$ sequences is a little trickier: if the last bit is 1, add 001; if the last bit is 0, add 010.

It's clear that these changes all produce friendly sequences (for the length $n-3$ sequences, having 1001 at the end is valid and, for 0010, it has to be 10010 otherwise that length $n-3$ sequence would have had to end 00 which is not possible).  Are the sequences created distinct?  Since no length $n-1$ sequence can end in 00, there's no overlap between adding a 1 to those and adding 001 to the length $n-3$ sequences that end in a 1.  Similarly, no length $n-2$ sequence can end in 00, so there's no overlap between adding 10 to those the adding 010 to the length $n-3$ sequences that end with 10.

Answer (score 3):

Your reasoning is not quite correct.  The reason is that an $n$-friendly sequence can also be formed in a way you don't consider: by adding a $1$ to the end of a sequence of length $n-1$ that is *almost* friendly.  Let's call an unfriendly sequence "almost friendly" (AF) if all its bits except the last one are adjacent to a $1$.

Starting from an AF sequence of length $n$ ending in $0$, you can add a $1$ to get an AF sequence.  Starting from an AF sequence of length $n$ ending in $1$, you can add a $1$ to get a friendly sequence ending in $1$.  Starting from a friendly sequence ending in $1$, you can add either bit to get a friendly sequence.  Finally, starting from a friendly sequence ending in $0$, you can add either bit to get an AF sequence.  Defining $A_n$ (resp. $B_n$) to be the number of friendly sequences of length $n$ ending in $0$ (resp. $1$), and $C_n$ (resp. $D_n$) to be the number of almost friendly sequences of length $n$ ending in $0$ (resp. $1$), we have
$$
\begin{eqnarray}
A_{n+1} &=& B_n \\
B_{n+1} &=& B_n + D_n \\
C_{n+1} &=& A_n \\
D_{n+1} &=& A_n + C_n
\end{eqnarray}
$$
Starting with $(A_1, B_1, C_1, D_1)=(0,0,1,1)$, this gives the total ($A+B$) number of friendly sequences of length $n$ as $0, 1, 3, 4, 5, 9, 16, 25, 39, 64, 105, 169,\ldots$.  So $n=11$ is the first to exceed $100$.  (Also, this is sequence [A195971](https://oeis.org/A195971) in the OEIS.)

Comment: What according to you are the values of $F_1 , F_2$? As 0,2 are clearly not first two terms.